# prove that 2016 is a self-composable number

Tags: mathematics

Define a number **self-composable** if it may be computed using just the digits of the number itself (used just once) and the following operations:

- basic operations ( $+, -, \times, \div$)
- less than basic operations ($x^y, \;\sqrt x, \;x!, \;x.y$ (decimal point))
- extended operations ($.x, \; .\overline{x}$)
- parentheses at will

If the digits of the mathematical operation are in the same order as in the number itself, the number is said **orderly self-composable**.

For example, 25 is self-composable ($5^2 = 25$) and 343 is orderly self-composable, since $(3+4)^3 = 343$.

2016 is self-composable too: find how.

Comment: Can I do things like (20)^(16) ?

Comment: no, concatenation of digits is not allowed since otherwise you might express 2016 as.... 2016 :-)

Comment: Let's say that concatenation is allowed except for the trivial case in which you are writing the number that you start with: anyway in this case it is not necessary.

Comment: What are the extended operations?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think I have it

> $ 2016 = ({.2} / {.\overline1} + 0!) \times 6!$

Also as pointed out by Matt in the comments, we can swap things around so that 2016 is orderly self-composable

> $ 2016 = ({.2} / .\overline{0!} + 1) \times 6!$

Comment: Seems good to me. Good job. And here I was trying to write a graph explorer...

Comment: you are right! (Ok, it was not easy)

Comment: Ah, relies on the (somewhat arbitrary) rule that `0!` = `1`.  I've always felt that it should simply be undefined for numbers < `1`...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman That is not arbitrary at all. By definition we have $n! = (n - 1)! * n$. And if we take $n=1$ we get $1! = 0!$. There is even a (much more involved) generalization to all real numbers (except negative integers).

Comment: I don't know if $.\overline{0!}$ is actually valid mathematical notation...

Comment: It was admittedly more clear in an order-of-operations sense with the notation that was provided in the original text of the question by the OP.

Comment: @kasperd - That's one definition.  I prefer the one that comes from the name, in that the "factorial" of N has as "factors" all positive integers up to N.  Since no non-zero number can have 0 as a factor, it's explicitly excluded.  The other definition doesn't even hold, since `0!` does not equal `(0-1)! * 0`, since `-1!` is undefined (and even if it weren't, you're still multiplying it by 0, which would mean that `0! = <something> * 0 = 0`).

Comment: @DarrelHoffman You may be interested in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20969/prove-0-1-from-first-principles . The many answers there, including mine at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1094926/198422 , suggest a lot of reasons why you'd want $0!$ to equal $1$. I would say that the equation $0! = 1$ is conventionally accepted among the mathematics community: just see the link; there's not really any dissent as to what the "right value" of $0!$ should be.

Comment: $0!=1$, but $.\overline{0!}$ is really strange.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman $0!$ would be the product of everything in the empty set. The only meaningful definition of the product of everything in the empty set is $1$ just like the sum of everything in the empty set has to be $0$. The recursive definition of $n!$ does need a basis somewhere, and that basis is defining $0!$ because that's the smallest integer for which it makes sense. It cannot be extended to $-1!$ because that would require a division by zero. It can however be extended to have a meaning for all reals except the negative integers.

Answer (score 3):

> find divisors of 2016 that contains its own numbers: $2016/2 \rightarrow 1008/2 \rightarrow 504/2 \rightarrow 252/2 \rightarrow 126/126 \rightarrow 1$

therefore;

> we can't use $2^4$ since $4$ is not in $2016$ but we can do $2^2$ for $2$:  $2^2 \times 2^2 \times 126 \times 1^0$

Comment: in your solution you are using the 2 more than once, and you are concatenating digits. Both of these are not allowed.

Comment: oh I see. missed the point "just once" will think some more :)